# React Stop component updating when parent updates

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a nightmare with updating components.

I'm using a diagram library https://www.gitbook.com/book/projectstorm/react-diagrams/details

To create a load of nodes that link together.

On the nodes I'm using https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc

This creates a sortable list of entities.

There are input fields in the entities. Everytime I click a field to enter text, it seems the diagram is updating, the node then updates and I lose focus on the field.

I've used  `shouldComponentUpdate` in the node when the sortable list sends data and set a flag to stop updating when it receives data, this works for the first letter but then I immediately lose focus again.

What way is there to stop a parent updating a child, or keeping focus so I can keep typing when the node is updated?

Comment: Have you added the ```e.preventDefault();``` to your handling the input section?

Comment: can you post your code? even if its a thin wrapper around the libraries

Comment: then general answer to your question is to update parent onBlur / enterKey instead of on keypress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just could do something like below. Not 100% sure it'll work as you need. But just try it.
Will have to call textBoxLostFocus() when typing is finished (when loosing focus of the textbox)

```
constructor(){
   super()
   this.state={
      diagramUpdateFlag: false
   }
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState){
   if(this.state.diagramUpdateFlag === nextState.diagramUpdateFlag){
      return false
   } else {
      return true
   }
}

textBoxLostFocus(){
   this.setState({diagramUpdateFlag: !this.state.diagramUpdateFlag})
}
```